# How do you use the Bootstrap Grid?

Tags: html, css

I used the bootstrap grid and it doesn't seem to be styling the html code using css. I put down the code below and this is my result. column column cloumn

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">

<script src="node_module/bootstrap/dist/js/boostrap.bundle.js"></script>
<div class="container-md border">

  <div class="container-md">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        Column
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        Column
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        Column
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a version with remote CDNs:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container-md border">

  <div class="container-md">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        Column
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        Column
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        Column
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does the version with CDN link I've added do what you expect? Have you checked the developer tool's network tab if your CSS is actually loaded correctly?

Comment: Bootstrap has been outlawed, sorry.

Comment: I figured it out. I was missing an extra line of code. I have to practice more html and css.